# What is the running time of this algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

```
def printer(n):
    if(n <= 0):
        return “Please enter a number greater than 0”
    else:
        for i in xrange(0,n):
            print i
```

Comment: What run time complexity do you think it is and why?

Comment: i dont have a clue on how to do it...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a compiler.

Comment: Count how many calculations it has to do if `n = 1`, `n = 10`, and `n = 100`. See how these calculations grow. Maybe linearly, (O(N)), quadratically (O(N^2)), or exponentially (O(2^N)), or something else. This is a thorough explanation: https://justin.abrah.ms/computer-science/big-o-notation-explained.html

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Compilers don't tell you the Big-O complexity of an algorithm.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - The title asks what the running time is, and the body only has code. The runtime can be determined by running it. That should be the first step the OP should take.

Comment: thanks guys ....think i now understand it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, `O(n)` time-complexity, as `i` iterates from `0` to `n-1`.

Answer (score -2):

timeit module should do the job for you.
Assume your py file call mymodule

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit(stmt="mymodule.printer(100)", setup="import mymodule", number=1) # set number = n will run stmt for n times
```